# Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Decimal'

Tags: prisma

I want to manually create an object of my Prisma schema

```js
const order: Order = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'Name',
  price: 99
}

...

// Somewhere in autogenerated file by Prisma
export type Order = {
  id: string
  name: string
  price: Prisma.Decimal
}
```

But it throws an error

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Decimal'.
```

How to convert javascript `number` to Prisma `Decimal` type?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to fix this error by using `Prisma.Decimal` class

Example

```js
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

const order: Order = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'Name',
  price: new Prisma.Decimal(99)
}
```

See [Working with Decimal](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-fields#working-with-decimal) documentation of Prisma

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just make the number a string first:

`` new Decimal(`${expectedOutAmount}`) ``