# does typescript can defind decimal type?

Tags: typescript

in the database ([MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/)) the price is defined as [decimal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html), then I use [tRPC](https://trpc.io/) to fetch data, when I want to use the value it show errors.

```
 Types of property 'price' are incompatible.
    Type 'Decimal | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

I try to find what type can I define decimal but only found number.

**prisma:**

```
model project{
  price  Decimal?  @db.Decimal(19, 4)
...
}
```

**frontend**

```
type projectType = {
price:number
...
}
```

I try use BigInt still error
`Type 'Decimal | null' is not assignable to type 'BigInt'.`

tempoary use any type to skip the error.
how to solve this problem?

**edit**

```
  price  Decimal  @db.Decimal(19, 4)
```

remove the question mark to fix the null problem, but the error is same.

Comment: You either have `number` or `BigInt`

Comment: _"but the error is same"_ can't be true. The error mentioned `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answers from [Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Decimal'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71942079/error-type-number-is-not-assignable-to-type-decimal)

```
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

type projectType = {
price:Prisma.Decimal
...
}
```

and the doc here ["Decimal"](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-fields#working-with-decimal)